# SoftSerial Not Working ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to communicate with my ESP8266 module through Arduino Mega with the ESP's Rx pin connected to Mega's Pin 7 the ESP's Tx pin connected to Mega's Pin 6. I tried to run the following test code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(6, 7);

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
 Serial.begin(115200);
 while (!Serial) {
   ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
 }

  Serial.println("Started");

 // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
 esp8266.begin(9600);
 esp8266.write("AT\r\n");
}

void loop() {
 if (esp8266.available()) {
  Serial.write(esp8266.read());
 }
 if (Serial.available()) {
  esp8266.write(Serial.read());
 }
}
```

I get no response from the ESP8266 module. I then tried to use the Mega's dedicated Tx and Rx pins (1 and 0 respectively). I can send commands using the serial monitor and it replies. First I sent `AT+CIOBAUD=9600` under a 115200 baud to change the baud rate of my ESP module to 9600. Then under 9600 baud I sent `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0`. It replied `OK` for both as expected. I tried again to run this program but I'm still getting no response from the ESP 8266 module. I also tried simply switching the Rx and Tx pins just to be safe. Still doesn't work. Any ideas on what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: @Billa Yes, it prints 'Started' but then does not reply with anything.

Comment: @Billa Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This question should be moved to https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Billa Right, but I changed the baud rate to be 9600 so it works with a SoftSerial port.

Comment: The baud rate of serial monitor, esp module and the arduino should be same. Better set it to 9600.

Comment: Why are you trying to use software serial and hardware serial on pins 0 and 1 (thats already connected to PC), if the Mega has 3 other hardware serial interfaces?

Comment: @gre_gor I mean as a separate test I used pins 0 and 1 under the Blink program to send AT commands to change the baud rate to 9600 and that worked. Now I'm trying to use a SoftSerial with pins 6 and 7 using this test program. My esp doesn't reply when using the SoftSerial with this code? I'd also like it to work with Uno which only has 1 Tx/Rx pair.

Comment: @gre_gor I just connected it to the Uno and it works! But I'm not really sure why it doesn't work on Mega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned in comments, `SoftwareSerial esp(6,7)` works on `UNO` but not on `Mega`. That should be hint big enough to google the [Arduino SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) reference page, particularly the Limitation section.

In short, unlike `UNO` the `Mega` doesn't have Pin Change Interrupt capability on all pins. So you can't have Rx pin on pin 6.